# How to use Sass::Engine's render_with_sourcemap

Tags: ruby, sass

After looking at the [documentation for render_with_sourcemap](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Engine.html#render_with_sourcemap-instance_method) (and unfortunately unable to find any example uses of this), I was under the impression that the following should work:

```
@source_dir = './sass/'
@target_dir = './css/'
@output = Sass::Engine.new(File.read(@source_dir + 'style.scss'), {
        cache_location: @source_dir + '.sass-cache',
        style: :compressed,
        syntax: :scss
}).render_with_sourcemap(@target_dir + 'style.css.map')
```

However, the error I'm getting is:

```
Error generating source map: couldn't determine public URL for the source stylesheet. (Sass::SyntaxError)
No filename is available so there's nothing for the source map to link to.
```

It works by simply using *render* (which doesn't need a parameter) instead of *render_with_sourcemap*, so I'm led to believe my filename is erroneous - however, I don't see what I'm doing wrong. I also tried `/style.css.map`, `./style.css.map` and `@target_dir + style.css.map`, all with no success (getting the same error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source code of the Engine class](https://github.com/sass/sass/blob/stable/lib/sass/engine.rb), I found that the error is thrown from `_render_with_sourcemap` if `@options[:filename]` is nil - initializing the function with that option resulted in successfully generating the sourcemap.

*The following code is the entire code needed to generate a css file and sourcemap for future reference*

```
@source = './sass/'
@target = './css/'
@output = Sass::Engine.new(File.read(@source + 'style.scss'), {
    cache_location: @source + '.sass-cache',
    filename: 'style.css',
    style: :compressed,
    syntax: :scss
}).render_with_sourcemap(@target + 'style.css.map')

# write css to file
File.write(@target, @output[0])

# write sourcemap to file
sourcemap_options = {
  :css_path => @target,
  :sourcemap_path => @target + 'style.css.map'
}
File.write(@target + 'style.css.map', @output[1].to_json(sourcemap_options))
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if it is not documented you should set the filename variable. After that you should get a sourcemap object.